# RegEx: Find multiple results in JSON, but only in specific field, ignore other fields

Tags: json, regex, powershell

With RegEx, AND using it in powershell, I want to find all backslashes in a specific field of a json, other field values must be ignored

Example: Find all backslases in "Find" fields, but not in Replace fields inthis source

```
{
    "Find"   :  "<HintPath>([\.]{2}\\){1}Common\\Debug\\",
    "Replace":  "<HintPath>..\Common\Release\"
},
{
    "Find"   :  "<HintPath>([\.]{2}\\){2}Common\\Debug\\",
    "Replace":  "<HintPath>..\..\Common\Release\"
},
{
    "Find"   :  "<HintPath>([\.]{2}\\){3}Common\\Debug\\",
    "Replace":  "<HintPath>..\..\..\Common\Release\"
},
{
    "Find"   :  "<HintPath>([\.]{2}\\){4}Common\\Debug\\",
    "Replace":  "<HintPath>..\..\..\..\Common\Release\"
},
{
    "Find"   :  "<HintPath>([\.]{2}\\){5}Common\\Debug\\",
    "Replace":  "<HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Common\Release\"
},
{
    "Find"   :  "<HintPath>([\.]{2}\\){6}Common\\Debug\\",
    "Replace":  "<HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Common\Release\"
}
```

This did not work for me:

```
(?<="Find")\\(?=\",)
```

Comment: Try [`(?m)(?:\G(?!\A)|^\s*"Find")\[^\\\n\]*\K\\\`](https://regex101.com/r/pWvCib/1).

Comment: that works :) it would be great if you can explain the regex in Detail? thanks

Comment: EDIT: if I remove the line break between the "," and "Replace" it still matches all backslashes in the Replace field. Can we avoid that somehow?

Comment: You seem to take some user input and put into a JSON. You need to manipulate the user input *before* it is put into JSON. So, rather than fix an issue, avoid it from the beginning.

Comment: JSON does not have "fields". It's just a string. If you want to do stuff with JSON, then parse it and do things with the resulting object. It is fool's errand to try to process/manipulate JSON, or any other non-trivial language, with regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works in powershell ($text holds the json string):

```
$find_regex = '\S*["'']Find["''][^"'']*["''](.*)["''],'
$result= Select-String $find_regex -InputObject $text -AllMatches
foreach($match in $result.matches) {
$backslash_escaped = $match.Groups[1].value -replace '\\','\\'
$text = $text -replace [Regex]::Escape($match.Groups[1].value), $backslash_escaped
}
```